# Base32 decode in actionscript

Tags: actionscript, decode, base32

How do I decode a Base32 encoded string in Actionscript?

/Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base32? Just out of curiosity: Who would use that? I suggest searching for a Base64 library (there are 2 or 3 on the web) and modifying it. Should be quite straight forward.

greetz
back2dos

Comment: Your rigth and I found one I could use.

http://ostermiller.org/base64_actionscript.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's a JavaScript library that does Base32:

http://www.tumuski.com/2010/04/nibbler/

It might just work out the box in ActionScript, since both are ECMAScript.

Comment: It probably works. I anyway choosed to use a base64 library instead. Thx for your answer.